# How can I make one Active Directory group a member of another group from the command line?

Tags: windows, active-directory, active-directory-group

In Active Directory, I want to add one group to another group from the command line.

For example, if I have a group "A" and a group "B" I want to add B to A, i.e., make B a member of A.  How can I do this from the command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "policy inheritance"?  What sort of policy?  Do you just mean that you want group B to be a member of group A?

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes,I want that group B to be a member of group A.

Comment: You might have better luck posting to Server Fault, since this isn't a programming question.